# error: cannot find symbol class MediaStyle after migrating to androidx

Tags: android, androidx

android.support.v4.media.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle() was working fine in a music player application but after migrating to android x I get this error: cannot find symbol class MediaStyle. Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In AndroidX, that specific style is located in a different package. You need to prepend the media style with 'androidx.media.app'.

In other words:

```
builder.setStyle(new androidx.media.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle());
```

Curiously enough, I didn't need to implement this package in my gradle file, so it could be something related to AndroidX internal dependencies.

Comment: This needs `implementation "androidx.media:media:1.1.0"`, as @Angel wrote.

Answer (score 16):

for my case, i need to add the following to my gradle file to find NotificationCompat.MediaStyle() class.

```
implementation "androidx.media:media:1.1.0"
```

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/media

```
NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
.setStyle(new androidx.media.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle());
```

note that notificationCompat.Builder is in a different package (androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat) from MediaStyle.

Answer (score 3):

Migrate `android.support.v4.media.app.NotificationCompat` to `androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat`

This looks like same answer @karan gave above. But the classes are different. Took me days to figure out that `androidx.media.app.NotificationCompat` was my problem.

The difference between the two; one is `androidx.core...`, the other is `androidx.media...`

Comment: Yeap, I meet the error same, you are right, karan is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

As you have migrated to androidX you need to use equivalent import for classes instead of using older support library classes.

Thus, replace 
`android.support.v4.media.app.NotificationCompat` with this androidX class `androidx.media.app.NotificationCompat`.
You can check migration guide further from here https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate