# How to use MediaStyle

Tags: android

Currently I want to implement media style notification with NotificationCompat.MediaStyle but unfortunately I am getting

> Can not resolve 'MediaStyle'

It looks like it have been removed . . . I am using  `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0`

I can't find the alternative solution for such problem, can someone please help. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to prepend the media style with 'androidx.media.app'.

More information here: [error: cannot find symbol class MediaStyle after migrating to androidx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56457402/error-cannot-find-symbol-class-mediastyle-after-migrating-to-androidx)